# 'Undefined Reference' to linker variable used in C source code

Tags: c, linker, arm, linker-errors, undefined-reference

I'm doing some programming on an ST ARM microcontroller, and for part of this I need to store some data in flash that will be persistent across boots.

For consistency across my project, I want to define the location of this data in my linker script, and then use this variable in my code. I've done this (for two separate regions).

The relevant part of my linker script:

```
MEMORY
{
    flash :             org = 0x08000000, len = 60k     /* Standard boot - No bootloader */
    flash_config_info : org = 0x0801F800, len = 1k      /* Location for config info storage */
    flash_boot_info :   org = 0x0801FC00, len = 1k      /* Location for boot info storage */
    ram :               org = 0x20000000, len = 20k  
}
```

The header for my boot info section:

```c
#ifndef BOOTLOADER_H_
#define BOOTLOADER_H_

#include <stdint.h>

extern uint32_t flash_boot_info;
#define BOOT_INFO_PAGE_ADDRESS (&flash_boot_info)

//...

#endif
```

The header for my configuration info section:

```c
#ifndef INFO_H_
#define INFO_H_

#include <stdint.h>

extern uint32_t flash_config_info;
#define INFO_CONFIG_PAGE_ADDRESS (&flash_config_info)

//...

#endif
```

My problem: I'm getting "undefined reference to" errors about the `flash_boot_info` variable at link time. I'm NOT getting the same errors about `flash_config_info`. It's important to note that if I switch the names of the variables, the error follows the location of reference, not the variable (I get errors about `flash_config_info` when it's referenced where `flash_boot_info` should be).

Does anyone have insight on why such an error might occur? I can't find any difference in how I'm referencing the variables, but some insight on where I might look would be much appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Check the linker configuration in your project settings, perhaps that `0x0801FC00` address is not defined there properly. Have you tried to "play around" with that address? For example, you know that `0x08000000` is probably a legal address, so change the length of the `flash` section from 60k to 59k, and then allocate the `flash_boot_info` section at `0x0800EC00`.

Comment: Also, don't use `-Text=`, etc with a custom linker file.  Probably *ld* should give a warning for this case as it does some really bizarre things if you use *memory regions* and specify where they should be with `-Text`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

The same thing can be accomplished by partitioning with-in the sections stanza.  For example,

```
MEMORY
{
    flash : org = 0x08000000, len = 64k
    ram :   org = 0x20000000, len = 20k  
}
SECTIONS
{
   .text {
      boot.o(.text);
      *(.text);
      *(.rodata);
   } > flash
   .data {
      *(.data);
   } > ram AT>flash
   . = ADDR(.text) + 0x1F800; /* to config position */
   .config { *(.config); } > flash
   . = ADDR(.text) + 0x1FC00; /* to boot position */
   .boot { *(.boot); } > flash
   .bss { *(.bss); } > ram
}
```

The main issue to contend with is that **ld** want to put everything in one memory region.  This is because you need to burn an image (binary) to just one device.  In reality, I think you only have one flash device and just want to divide the flash.  It is better to use the location counter (`.`) for this purpose.

You can pre-process the linker script and/or use constants to make the values *1f800* and *1fc00* more readable.  Using the memory regions looks better, but I think you will have a better experience using **sections** for this partitioning.

Comment: You may be able to get the memory regions to work, but I think it is the wrong tool for the job.  At least give a better rational of why you want to do it with memory regions, if this does not answer your question.